# How to get specific culture currency pattern

Tags: c#, string, format, currency

How do i get the currency pattern for a specific culture?

For Example:

Instead of using:

```
string.Format("{0:c}", 345.10)
```

I want to use this:

```
string.Format("#.##0,00 €;-#.##0,00 €", 345.10);
```

But how do i get the pattern string (like "#.##0,00 €;-#.##0,00 €") for each culture my application needs?

I cant use the "{0:c}" pattern because if the user switches the language the currency should be the same.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A `CultureInfo` contains a `NumberFormatInfo` and this class describes (among other things) how to format currency for that particular culture.

In particular you can use `CurrencyPositivePattern` and `CurrencyNegativePattern` to determine if the currency symbol is placed before or after the amount and of course `CurrencySymbol` to get the correct currency symbol. All this information is used by .NET when the `C` format specifier is used.

You can read more about the [NumberFormatInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) on MSDN.

The code below demonstrates some of the steps required to format currency properly. It only uses `CurrencySymbol`, `CurrencyPositivePattern` and `CurrencyDecimalDigits` and thus is incomplete:

```
var amount = 123.45M;
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK");

var numberFormat = cultureInfo.NumberFormat;
String formattedAmount = null;
if (amount >= Decimal.Zero) {
  String pattern = null;
  switch (numberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern) {
    case 0:
      pattern = "{0}{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}";
      break;
    case 1:
      pattern = "{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}{0}";
      break;
    case 2:
      pattern = "{0} {1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}";
      break;
    case 3:
      pattern = "{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "} {0}";
      break;
  }
  formattedAmount = String.Format(cultureInfo, pattern, numberFormat.CurrencySymbol, amount);
}
else {
  // ...
}

Console.WriteLine(formattedAmount);
```

Of course you could simply use:

```
var amount = 123.45M;
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK");
var formattedAmount = String.Format(cultureInfo, "{0:C}", amount);
Console.WriteLine(formattedAmount);
```

Comment: This way i'm trying. Do i have to implement a switch determing wich pattern is used by my self? The CurrencyNegativePattern for example has 15 options. Or is there a way to get the string value instead of the int number? Edit: You already answered.

Answer (score 18):

I think what you're asking is how to change the currency symbol but keep the culture-specific formatting. You can do this by getting a copy of the current `NumberFormatInfo` and modifying the `CurrencySymbol` property:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de");
// pretend we are german

var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
nfi.CurrencySymbol = "$$$";
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(nfi,"{0:c}",345.10));
```

This will output:

```
345,10 $$$
```

Without changing the `CurrentCulture` it outputs (for me):

```
$$$345.10
```

Comment: This is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

You need to format your currency/double using:

```
money.ToString("C", culture);
```

The hard part is actually getting the right culture based on the ISO code. I do not know how you keep track of the culture you need. Keep in mind this is simply the **formatting** of your money, not **conversion** to different currencies/cultures!

More detail:

ISOCurrencySymbol is a part of RegionInfo, which you can create based on CultureInfo, which you can retrieve from your current thread's culture settings. You should create a singleton which implements a dictionary to convert from ISOCurrencyCode to CultureInfo.

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty approach that works for all number formats is:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("el-GR");
var numberFormat = (NumberFormatInfo)culture.NumberFormat.Clone();
numberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "€";  // Force the currency symbol regardless of culture
var specifier = "C";                // Or any other format specifier
var positivePattern = 1110.ToString(specifier, numberFormat).Replace('1', '#');
var negativePattern = (-1110).ToString(specifier, numberFormat).Replace('1', '#');
var pattern = positivePattern + ";" + negativePattern;
```

In this case, pattern equals "#.##0,00 €;-#.##0,00 €".  This avoids a lot of headaches trying to figure out all of the permutations.  I appreciate the question being asked, as it helped and forced me to find an easier answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `string.Format("{0:N2} €", 345.10)`? This should format to 2 decimal places in the users culture followed by a space and the euro symbol.

Comment: I thought about something like this, but in some languages the currency symbol is before the value expamle: "SFr. 123'456.00"

Comment: I think that I misunderstood the question then. I thought that you were trying to maintain the currency as euros irrespective of the locale.

Answer (score 1):

The test below illustrates how you can achieve this:

```
    [Test]
    public void DisplayEurosInGreeceAndEngland()
    {
        var val = 125.22m;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
            = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
              = new CultureInfo("el-GR");

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:n} €", val));

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
            = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
              = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:n} €", val));
    }
```

By using the standard decimal notation from the currently selected culture, you can display any given value skipping the currency, which you can treat separately.

Comment: Thanks but i can't use this solution because i use a DevExpress Grid and this only accepts string format patterns.

Comment: I think you can use {0:n} specifically. Have a look at the information here: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2141

Comment: The `{0:n}` format uses the _Number_ format, the library goes to great lengths to distinguish that from the _Currency_ format. And in some countries that matters a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For Positive and negative number one can use below code snippet for culture

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> cultures = new List<string> { "ca-ES", "co-FR", "cs-CZ", "cy-GB", "da-DK", "de-AT", "de-CH", "de-DE", "de-LI", "de-LU", "dsb-DE", "en-US", "en-GB" };

        var amount = -16.34M;

        foreach (var c in cultures)
        {
            var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(c);

            var numberFormat = cultureInfo.NumberFormat;
            String formattedAmount = null;
            if (amount >= Decimal.Zero)
            {
                String pattern = null;
                switch (numberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern)
                {
                    case 0:
                        pattern = "{0}{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        pattern = "{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}{0}";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pattern = "{0} {1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        pattern = "{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "} {0}";
                        break;
                }
                formattedAmount = String.Format(cultureInfo, pattern, numberFormat.CurrencySymbol, amount);

            }
            else if (amount < Decimal.Zero)
            {
                String pattern = null;
                switch (numberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern)
                {
                    case 0:
                        pattern = "({0}{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "})";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        pattern = numberFormat.NegativeSign + "{0}{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pattern = "{0}" + numberFormat.NegativeSign + "{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        pattern = "{0}{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}" + numberFormat.NegativeSign;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        pattern = "({1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}{0})";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        pattern = numberFormat.NegativeSign + "{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}{0}";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        pattern = "{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}" + numberFormat.NegativeSign + "{0}";
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        pattern = "{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}{0}" + numberFormat.NegativeSign;
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        pattern = numberFormat.NegativeSign + "{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "} {0}";
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        pattern = numberFormat.NegativeSign + "{0} {1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}";
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        pattern = "{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "} {0}" + numberFormat.NegativeSign;
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        pattern = "{0} {1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}" + numberFormat.NegativeSign;
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        pattern = "{0}" + " " + numberFormat.NegativeSign + "{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}";
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        pattern = "{1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "}" + numberFormat.NegativeSign + " " + "{0}";
                        break;
                    case 14:
                        pattern = "({0} {1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "})";
                        break;
                    case 15:
                        pattern = "({1:N" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits + "} {0})";
                        break;
                }
                formattedAmount = String.Format(cultureInfo, pattern, numberFormat.CurrencySymbol, amount * -1);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(formattedAmount);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```