# change currency of string format

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I've got a string formatter:

```
String.Format("{0:c}", team.sales);
```

when I do this, the string is printed with a pound sign(£)
is there any way for me to force formatter to show dollars($) instead?

Comment: This may be of help though, [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924067/how-to-get-specific-culture-currency-pattern)

Comment: Maybe look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
int money = 125000000;
CultureInfo us = CultureInfo.ReadOnly(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
String result = String.Format(us, @"{0:c}", money);
```