# How to get the format string for a specified currency and culture

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, currency-formatting

I have SSRS reports that display currency amounts. They need to be both culture aware and currency aware. Some reports show different currencies in the same table. I have no trouble with culture awareness. It's currency formatting that's the trouble. **Importantly, when I export to Excel, the values in these currency fields must be sortable as numbers. That means the cell values must be numbers, so I cannot use the normal .ToString("C", culture) functions that so many other posts end up with.** I need to keep the numeric value in the field and to apply .NET's format string to the number (e.g. "'$'#,0.00;('$'#,0.00)"). This way, Excel will treat the value as a number for sorting purposes but display the correctly formatted currency.

Is it possible to use code to modify a NumberFormatInfo instance and then somehow return the string value of the formatter, such as "'€'#,0.00;('€'#,0.00)"?

```
var numberFormat = new CultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat;
numberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "€";
return numberFormat.GetCurrencyFormatString(); //this is an imaginary function that I need to return "'€'#,0.00;('€'#,0.00)"
```

I have tried programmatically setting the currency symbol based on the currency information of each row. As far as I know, SSRS does not allow me to use an Expression to set the currency symbol. It only offers a dropdown list.

My users don't like it when I show the currency code (e.g. USD, CAD), so I'm stuck with showing the symbol (e.g. $, CA$).

Comment: here are some hints.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924067/how-to-get-specific-culture-currency-pattern.
If you want to export it to excel, the formatting is not necessary. Excel will understand unformatted numbers much better, and will apply it's own formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the response Holger. But, the answer in that post recommends using the String.Format() function, which will return a string. If I use a string in the cell, Excel will sort as a string. Also, one of my requirements is to show different currencies in the same table. Excel can't know which currency symbol to apply unless I tell it which one to use. That's why I need the format string - because Excel understands it.

Comment: You asked for formatting, of course you will get a string, something else cannot be formatted. What to recommend depends on how you try to transfer anything to excel - via the clipboard; it's most likely a text. Via Interop, you can pass your double directly. With Copy&Paste Excel will parse the incoming text as good as it can, I don't think it will recognize more than one symbol as a currency, nor recognize any other units. And as a fallback, if it cannot be parsed, it remains a string. So as more formatting you put on the number, as more likely it will remain a string.

Comment: I'm specifically talking about SSRS here. When SSRS exports to Excel, the value in the cell must be a number. The formatting applied to the number is what I need to get my hands on. If I apply a format of '$'#,0.00;('$'#,0.00) to a number, Excel will still know that the value is a number, which is great. And it will format the number as a dollar amount. I'm looking for a function that gives me something like '$'#,0.00;('$'#,0.00) that respects the correct currency symbol and also the current culture settings, which affect where currency symbols are displayed (either before or after the number)

Comment: As long as you do not clarify what you mean by "export", this discussion is useless. You can use Interop-Api, you can use the clipboard, you can use clipboard as either plain text, or html-formatted, you can "save as" xlsx-files without contacting excel at all.

Comment: I'm referring to SSRS' built-in functionality to automatically convert reports to Excel format.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you'll need to manually construct this format string using the `CultureInfo` class.

Using the docs on `CurrencyPositivePattern` and `CurrencyNegativePattern` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern?view=netframework-4.8) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern?view=netframework-4.8)), I've put together something that works but might need some tweaking:

```
string GetCurrencyFormat(CultureInfo culture)
{            
    //we'll use string.Format later to replace {0} with the currency symbol
    //and {1} with the number format
    string[] negativePatternStrings = { "({0}{1})", "-{0}{1}", "{0}-{1}", "{0}{1}-", "({1}{0})",
                            "-{1}{0}", "{1}-{0}", "{1}{0}-", "-{1} {0}", "-{0} {1}",
                            "{1} {0}-", "{0} {1}-", "{0} -{1}", "{1}- {0}", "({0} {1})",
                            "({1} {0})" };
    string[] positivePatternStrings = { "{0}{1}", "{1}{0}", "{0} {1}", "{1}{0}" };

    var numberFormat = culture.NumberFormat;

    //Generate 0's to fill in the format after the decimal place
    var decimalPlaces = new string('0', numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits);

    //concatenate the full number format, e.g. #,0.00
    var fullDigitFormat = $"#{numberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator}0{numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator}{decimalPlaces}";

    //use string.Format on the patterns to get the positive and 
    //negative formats
    var positiveFormat = string.Format(positivePatternStrings[numberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern],  
                                       numberFormat.CurrencySymbol, fullDigitFormat);
    var negativeFormat = string.Format(negativePatternStrings[numberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern], 
                                       numberFormat.CurrencySymbol, fullDigitFormat);

    //finally, return the full format
    return $"{positiveFormat};{negativeFormat}";
}
```

This returns `$#,0.00;($#,0.00)` for `en-US`, `£#,0.00;-£#,0.00` for `en-GB`, for example.

Comment: Thank you KMoussa. This is very close to what I want. It seems to work well for currencies where the symbol appears before the number. But, some culture formats call for the currency symbol after the number, like this: "#,0 'CA$';(#,0 'CA$')". I was hoping .NET would have a way to just return what it's using (given the culture), but it looks like I'd have to do something like this to get the job done!

Comment: I'm sure there are other culture-specific nuances that I am not aware of, too - not just the position of the currency symbol. That's why I was hoping the framework (which is aware of these nuances, given the culture) would spit out the format string it's using.